# Showing $f = 0$ on $[0,\infty)$ if $g(x):=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-xt}\,dt = 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

So given $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ bounded and continuous, I need to show $f$ is identically $0$ on the positive real line given
$$g(x):=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-xt}\,dt = 0 \quad x > 0$$.
My thought was to use Stone-Weierstrass on some arbitrary interval $[0,M]$ to show either $\int_0^M f^2(t)\,dt = 0$ or $\int_0^M f^2(t)e^{-xt}\,dt = 0$, but it hasn't been cooperating with me.

Any hints? Am I on the right track? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Laplace Transform pair is unique.

Comment: @Dr.MV Right, but I have to prove that rigorously using classical analysis.

Comment: Have you tried googling a proof of the fact that the inverse Laplace transform is unique?

Comment: prove that the polynomials in $e^{-t}$ are denses in the space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^+$ ? thus if the projection of $f$ onto these is everywhere $0$, $f$ is almost everywhere $0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $n\in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and let $u=e^{-t}$ so $t=-\ln(u)$ and $du=-e^{-t} dt=-u dt$

Then:

$$ \begin{align*}\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-xt}dt&=\int_0^1f(-\ln(u)) e^{-x(-\ln(u))} \frac{du}{u}\\
&=\int_0^1f(-\ln(u)) e^{x\ln(u)} \frac{du}{u}\\
&=\int_0^1f(-\ln(u)) u^{x-1} du
\end{align*}$$

Let $x=n+1$, then:

$$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-xt}dt=\int_0^1f(-\ln(u))u^{n}du$$

Then apply the following lemma:

**Lemma** if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 f(u) u^n du=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ then $f\equiv 0$.

Proof is a straightforward application of Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Thus $f(-\ln(u))\equiv 0$ and $f(x)\equiv 0$.

For more see: http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/laplaceuniqueness.pdf

Comment: A remark: As $f$ is not supposed to have a limit if $t\to +\infty$ ($f$ is only bounded), one cannot say that the function $f(-\log u)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. But of course, as $f$ is bounded, $g(u)=uf(-\log u)$ has a continuation as a continuous function on $[0,1]$, putting $g(0)=0$, and your argument apply to $g$. (+1).

Comment: Y'know, you can get so myopically focused on employing theorems and propositions that you forget about using a change of variables to help you out. That was certainly my ailment this time. Thanks for the help!